# How to make a generic function for Jackson/ObjectMapper in java?

Tags: java

So I have these methods:

```
private List<ClientRepresentation> toClientRepresentation(String json) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<ClientRepresentation>>() {
        });
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse json.");
    }
}

private List<RoleRepresentation> toRoleRepresentation(String json) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<RoleRepresentation>>() {
        });
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse json.");
    }
}

private List<UserRepresentation> toUserRepresentation(String json) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(userJson, new TypeReference<List<UserRepresentation>>() {
        });
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse json.");
    }
}
```

You can see these are similar... Would like to have one method for these... Something like this:

```
private List<T> toObjectsList(String json, Class classToConvert) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<classToConvert>>() {
        });
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse json.");
    }
}
```

Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that `Class<?>` can be used to convey only type-parameter-less constructs. Thus, something like `List<String>` **cannot** be conveyed with it (only 'List' - any and all lists, unparameterized - that is the only thing Class can convey). If you ever want `toObjectsList` to return something like a `List<Map<String, Object>>` you are dead in the water on this: The entire setup fundamentally can't do it. So, first consider whether this is a good idea: You are handicapping yourself, that your `toObjectsList` method cannot ever return lists of type-argsed types. Presumably, if you're willing to document this and sign up to tacle such needs by not using `toObjectsList` and writing a custom readValue-based method instead, you're good to go.

Assuming you're on board with this restriction, the question boils down to: How does one construct an STT (Super-Type-Token, that TypeReference thing with the brackets after it) dynamically?

This should be doable, using the [`TypeFactory`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html) class.

For example, `constructParametricType(List.class, List.class, classToConvert);`.

We then need to address some other errors in your code:

- That exception handling is *deplorable*. You're tossing away all the useful info, and replacing it with entirely useless information. Don't write a catch block that fails to address the issue, unless that catch block preserves all information. Also, by convention exception messages do not end in punctuation.
- You are using a `<T>` in these methods, but you need to declare that T exists, first.
- `Class`, itself, is parameterized.

This gets us to:

```
private <T> List<T> toObjectsList(String json, Class<T> classToConvert) {
    JavaType typeTarget = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
        .constructParametricType(List.class, List.class, classToConvert);

    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeTarget);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // pass the original exception along as cause, preserving info.
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse json", e);
    }
}
```

(You may have to cast to `List<T>`, but I don't think it'll be needed due to some dubious hackery on jackson's part).